# In Cucumber-JUnit, is there a way to control the order in which features get reported?

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am running a basic Cucumber-Jvm test with two features called "Basic Math" and "Advanced Math" (in files `basic_math.feature` and `advanced_math.feature` respectively).

However, when the HTML report gets generated "Advanced Math" gets displayed before "Basic Math", whereas I would like "Basic Math" to appear *before* "Advanced Math". This is not trivial since if I can organise the output more logically, then the reports will be more accessible to our business analysts and QA department and the more traction I will be able to get.

I know I could try to do some sort of XSLT post processing with a Maven plugin, but I'm looking for someway to define it in code using annotations. Is there such a way? `Cucumber.@Options.features` actually defines the `.feature` file locations, and `Cucumber.@Options.name` is for rexexps that determine which features get run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I have observed. Cucumber picks up feature files for execution in sorted order. 
If you can name your feature files so that basic_math is picked up first, say, rename feature files as 01basic_math.feature and 02advanced_math.feature, then the report will show basic_math tests first.